# tar exclude not working as expected

Tags: gnu-tar

I am trying to create a .tar file of the filesystem but exclude the `/proc` directory.

The command I have tried is:

```
tar -czvf mytar.tgz / --exclude='/proc'
```

But this does not exclude the directory.

I have also tried it without the single quotes.

```
# tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.31
```

How can I exclude the directory?

Comment: Are you trying to create a backup? If yes, this is probably not a good approach.

Comment: Did you get any form of diagnostic messages from that `tar` command, like `The following options were used after any non-optional arguments in archive create or update mode.  These options are positional and affect only arguments that follow them.  Please, rearrange them properly.`  See also the `--one-file-system` option for GNU `tar`.  Also consider using backup software for doing backups, like `restic` or `borgbackup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the comment about this not being the best approach but just in terms of answering your issue - your version of `tar` requires that the `--exclude` options have to be placed at the beginning of the `tar` command.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/984204

```
tar --exclude='/proc' -czvf mytar.tgz /
```